# Django Model generalized condition

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, orm, django-admin

How can I add a generalized condition in django models like if I filter using ORM object the condition should automatically get added.
I have done similar in cake PHP and YII  where I actually get the query ORM and I can add a condition that gets attached to the query and later the query is fired.
Looking for similar kind of function in Django for Users Model.
**User.objects.filter(date_joined__range=(start_date_time, end_date_time))**
I want whenever I filter using this it should add a condition to the query.

Answers and suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you, but I think what you're after is a [custom `Manager`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#modifying-initial-manager-querysets).

Comment: Thanks for that but I am worried if I can do that for Django User Model.
As it must have been used directly everywhere. Like **from django.contrib.auth.models import User**.